AWS S3 Directory Bucket requests time out
I have a project that uses AWS S3 Buckets to store files, but I find that it is really slow to pull the full list and then request the metadata for each one.
I just learned about Directory Buckets, which are supposed to be faster, so I made one and put a few files in it.
However, I can't seem to get it to actually return any information on it.
I want to just get a list of the buckets to start to make sure that I am able to do that much, so I use:
S3Client client = new S3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

ListDirectoryBucketsRequest bucketsRequest = new ListDirectoryBucketsRequest();
       
ListDirectoryBucketsResponse listDirectory = await client.connection.ListDirectoryBucketsAsync(bucketsRequest);

And after a few minutes I get this error:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (s3express-control.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:80)'

Everything works fine for the normal buckets, so I am very confused why this isn't.

As per the AWS documentation for C#
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/directory-buckets-objects-ListExamples.html, you may try this way..
var listDirectoryBuckets = await amazonS3Client.ListDirectoryBucketsAsync(new ListDirectoryBucketsRequest
{
    MaxDirectoryBuckets = 10
})
.ConfigureAwait(false);


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Thanks @JeremyCaney, updated the documentation link provided by AWS
